# How to convert String to Date in Java or how to take user input in java,util.date in the form of dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, java.util.date

```
String ="12-12-1212"; // as input

Date date="12-12-1212"  //as output
```

or

how to take input in `Java.util.date` in  the form of `dd-mm-yyyy` form

Comment: There is DOZENS of example on this forum, and DOZENS outside this forum

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please search the site and/or the net. This question has been covered many times already, so you’ll find a good answer out there quickly.

Comment: Why do you want a `Date` object? The `Date` class is long outdated. I recommend [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `LocalDate` class instead. `java.time` is the modern Java date and time API.